# xUnit not always catching async exception

Tags: c#, async-await, xunit

I created a xUnit test that calls a method twice to ensure the 2nd call throws an exception saying the class instance is busy. Pretty straightforward.

```
[Fact]
public async Task RunTwice() {
    var P = Create();
    Task T1 = Task.Run(() => P.Run("test", null));
    Task T2 = Task.Run(() => P.Run("test", null));
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidOperationException>(() => Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { T1, T2 }));
}
```

Problem is, this test will randomly either succeed or fail!

The Run method starts like this

```
public IProcess WorkProcess;
private readonly object lockToken = new object();

public virtual CompletionStatus Run(string fileName, string arguments) {
    IProcess P;
    lock (lockToken) {
        if (WorkProcess != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        P = factory.Create();
        WorkProcess = P;
    }
...
```

Is this a buy in xUnit or am I doing something wrong? I know async support was added in xUnit 1.9. I'm using v2.4.1.

When I look at debug information, when the test fails, the exception is still thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're doing something wrong. `Task.Run` just schedules the work to the thread pool. Perhaps they'll try to call `Run` at the same time, perhaps one will happen after the other. There's a race condition inherent in what you're trying to do.

To solve this, you'll need some way for the unit test to control the code within `Run` and "pause" it.

Comment: This code is exactly to test a race condition. Considering the exception DOES get thrown, it seems to be either an issue or a limitation of xUnit.

Comment: @EtienneCharland: I'm saying that it's your *unit test* that has the race condition. Your test makes no guarantee that `P.Run` will be invoked twice at the same time; the calls could just as easily occur one after another.

Comment: In which case I would not see the exception being thrown in the Debug window. Or perhaps they do run one after the other in some cases, would have to double-check that.

Comment: You are right sir. The exception does not get thrown when I run several tests at once, because the tasks queue is busy and the 2nd task doesn't get run right away and thus there is no race; and when I run that test alone then it goes into a race.